# UDF with count always returns 0, or an error

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

So, I have a short UDF that takes a table (As Range) for an input, and would return the rows count as an output.

```
Function CALCROW(mytable As Range) As Double
   Dim rowNumber As Double
   statement
   CALCROW = rowNumber
End Function
```

For statement, I tried

```
rowNumber = myTable.Rows.Count
rowNumber = myTable.Count
rowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(myTable)
```

both gave 0, even though the table has 5 rows.

I even tried

```
rowNumber = myTable.Rows
rowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rows.Count(myTable)
rowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rows(myTable)
```

But for them I got the #VALUE error.

I know that if all I wanted to know the row count in excel i could just use =ROWS(myTable), but it isn't about that...

Comment: `rowNumber = myTable.Rows.Count` works for me.

Comment: How are you passing the table to the function? Also note your three attempts are counting very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the following code (in a module)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CALCROW(mytable As Range) As Long
   CALCROW = mytable.Rows.Count
End Function
```

and this as a formula

```
=CALCROW(B1:G8)
```

gives `8` which is correct. Instead of `B1:G8` you can even give a named range or ListObject name and it works.

Note that row counts can only be of type `Long`.

Comment: @PeterN Actually no, your code works too (I had no issues with your code). The type was not an issue, but it does not make any sense to declare it as `Double` as row numbers cannot have any decimals (a row `5.3` does just not exist) they are always integers. Therefore `Long` would be the correct type (because Excel has more rows than fit into `Integer`).